# Split one record into two based on its association's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a model Listing which has many Tickets, Tickets has `status` (either `on_sale` or `ordered`). Now I want query Listings and if it's tickets has different `status`, I want too split it into two records.

For instance, there is 1 listing which has 5 tickets, three of them `status` is `on_sale` and two of them is `ordered`, I want get 1 listing which has 3 tickets with its `status` (Listing also has `status`) is `on_sale` and 1 listing has 2 Tickets and the listing's status is `ordered`.

The point is 1 record split into two based on its association's status.

Comment: of course it is possible, but you have to write it ;) there's no automagical function for this in rails. try some code, and post it.

Comment: I can't write it, that's why I ask here, can you give me some hints?

Comment: And what happens to the original record now that you’ve created two new ones from it?

Comment: I don't want change origion db

Comment: @AndrewMarshall thanks for edit, sorry for not carefully enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, you need to representations of the Listing model in memory, but untouched in the DB.

You have 2 options, do it in Ruby or do it in SQL.

### Ruby

```
sale_listings = []
ordered_listings = []
Listing.all.each do |l|
  # assign tickets to their appropriate array      
  sale_listings << l if l.tickets.any?{|t| t.status == 'on_sale' }
  ordered_listings << l if l.tickets.any?{|t| t.status == 'ordered' }
end
```

### SQL (via Arel)

```
sale_listings = Listing.joins(:tickets).where("tickets.status = 'on_sale'")
ordered_listings = Listing.joins(:tickets).where("tickets.status = 'ordered'")
```

Both of these examples are untested (i.e. I did not try them before putting them here) and could be optimized.